# Custom LED control module for vehicle

Tags: led, automotive

I'd like to make a custom module to control the LED in my windshield but I don't know which parts I need.
Here's an example I've made in Javascript to show you exactly what I want
http://www.patriceguillemette.com/led-example.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are new to electronics, so I would just point out probably the easiest way for you to make something like this:

1. Arduino board - easy for newbies to program and implement some simple projects like yours.
2. LEDs and resistors.
3. Some MOSFETs, because you can't drive more than 40mA from microcontroller
4. Power supply - probably you can run it with your car 12V battery, but anyway you should sit and think about current, voltages and other stuff.

And of course the knowledge how to use it. Just google about LED driving with Arduino, there are million articles about it.

You could of course do it all analog using different analog ICs, but if you don't have much experience with it it probably will take more time.

Comment: I'd like to do it all analog. I know electronic components and what they do. I'm just not good enough to design my own circuits. I've tought about the arduino solution with transistor or relay to control the LED but i'd really like to do it analog. (less chances to break and more fun to do !

Comment: And FYI, here's the LED i've got from Ebay. They're working fine but that's not exactly what I want to control them.  http://www.ebay.ca/itm/54-18-LED-White-Amber-Emergency-Vehicle-Strobe-Flash-Light-Front-Rear-Grill-/291605363849

Comment: @PatriceGuillemette, there are a lot of different ways to do it in analog, on the first glance I would say you would need couple of 555 timers and some [74 series ICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7400_series) like some gates or latches... My advice would be to go with microcontroller anyway, it would be faster and probably cheaper. But if you still want to do analog - just go in small steps. Analog solutions are not that obvious to implement sometimes, if I would do something like this I would start with 555s and 74 series. If something wouldn't work - try to rethink the design.